# Neo4J how to count all the descendants of a single ancestor for a specified relationship type

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Does Neo4j provide a native query method to search and count all the descendants of a node for a specified relationship type such as REFERRED?
I'm trying to build a system to record 'A referred B' type of relationships for each referral.  It's required to real time count all the references from A down to the bottom which was caused by A.
The picture might look like this:

```
        A
       / \
      B   C
     / \  /\
    D  E F  G
   / \  / \  \ 
  M   N O  P  Q
```

ANY suggestion please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the Cypher query language to investigate Neo4j graphs;  and certainly with Cypher you can construct a query to give you the answer to your question.

Assuming for your question the A node has an id property of uid='A'and the relationship type is 'Referred' then the query could look like:

```
MATCH ({uid:'A'}) -[:Referred *1..]-> (n) RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n)
```

Here the first part

```
MATCH ({uid:'A'})
```

indicates a starting point for your query.  The Second part

```
-[:Referred *1..]->
```

describes which relations to follow.  The next part

```
(n)
```

names the terminating nodes for your query and lastly

```
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n)
```

returns a count of those nodes.

Comment: Thank you Evan!So, this query will count all the descendants nodes, for example, from B to Q in this graph?

Comment: If it is possible for a node to be referred multiple times, then to get the count of distinct descendants, you need to use `RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n)`.